# Prove $\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\begin{cases}2\tan^{-1}x,|x|<1\\-\pi+2\tan^{-1}x,|x|>1,x>0\\ \pi+2\tan^{-1}x,|x|>1,x<0\end{cases}$ using integration

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function

> Prove
>   $$
> \tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\begin{cases}2\tan^{-1}x,\quad|x|<1\\
> -\pi+2\tan^{-1}x,\quad |x|>1,x>0\\
> \pi+2\tan^{-1}x,\quad |x|>1,x<0\end{cases}
> $$
>   using differentiation and integration.

**My Attempt**

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\bigg)=\frac{1}{1+\Big(\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}\Big)^2}.\frac{(1-x^2).2-2x(-2x)}{(1-x^2)^2}\\=\frac{(1-x^2)^2}{(1+x^2)^2}.\frac{2.(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{2}{|1+x^2|}=\frac{2}{1+x^2}\\
\boxed{\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\int\frac{2}{1+x^2}dx=2\tan^{-1}x+C}
$$
How do I derive the value of $C$ for the respective range of $x$ ?

**Note:** I can evaluate the value of $C$ by putting different $x$ values,I am looking for more generalised way to derive the constant $C$.

Example.
$$
x=\sqrt{3},
\tan^{-1}-\sqrt{3}=2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{3}+C\\
C=-\pi/3-2\pi/3=-\pi
$$

Comment: I think you're forgetting an integral in the box

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "generalized", plugging in points is the most general method I can think of. Any other method will rely on special properties of the function, but every function you can always plug points in to.

Comment: Set standard values for $x$ in the given intervals. However, note you don't really need differentiation to establish these formulæ.

Comment: @NinadMunshi you mean putting the limit for the definite integral ?

Comment: @Bernard I am well aware of that. I am wondering how can I get a complete proof like this.

Comment: You can examine in which interval $2\arctan x$ lives according to the values of $x$. For instance, if $|x|<1$, $|\arctan x|<\frac\pi 4$, hence $|2\arctan x|<\frac\pi 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ with domain $x\ne \pm1$. Then, $f'(x) = \frac2{1+x^2}$ and

$$ f(x) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \frac2{1+t^2}dt 
=C+ 2\tan^{-1}x$$

where the constant $C$ is given by

$$C = f(x_0)- 2\tan^{-1}x_0 $$

Now, evaluate  $C$ in the three cases.

1) Case $-1<x<1$: Let $x_0=0$,

$$C = f(0)- 2\tan^{-1}(0) =0$$

2) Case $x>1$: Let $x_0 \to \infty $,

$$C= f(\infty)- 2\tan^{-1}(\infty) =0 - 2\cdot\frac\pi2=-\pi$$

3) Case $x<-1$:  Let $x_0 \to -\infty $,

$$C= f(-\infty)- 2\tan^{-1}(-\infty) =0 - 2\cdot\left(-\frac\pi2\right)=\pi$$